# Drupal PHP views - how to reference nested braket array variables?

Tags: 7, views

I did a dpm() on the path variable i have and I'm running into the issue of figuring out how to reference this variable. When I do a print_r() on the variable it shows that its [[path]]

I'm not sure how to reference that. I thought it might be $var[['path']] but that doesnt work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a plain PHP question for which the answer didn't change even if you we're not using Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, since the square brackets are part of the string they need to go inside the quotes, e.g.

```
$var['[path]']
```

Comment: omg. why did they do that.... I was trying to google this as if it was a new variable type that i never noticed. lol thanks clive!